# How do I replicate this effect?

Tags: css

How does the BBC News website create the changing colour effect you get if you roll over their most popular stories on this webpage http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-12336381 (see bottom right)

Comment: Care to include a screenshot of what you are pointing out?

Comment: I don't know what the affect is but look for it in HTML5.  It doesn't work in FF3.6 but it does work in the most current version of Chrome.

Comment: If http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8571/how-do-i-replicate-this-effect/8572#8572 is what you want, then that can either be jQuery or CSS. I think CSS is the proper way, but not 100% sure. Still a CSS-novice.

Comment: I think the questioner means this area http://i.imgur.com/xZAFJ.png. Sorry this isn't a comment but I don't have an account.

  [1]:

Answer (score 2):

At a guess they are using their own javascript library [glow](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/). It's like jquery but with wider browser support to meet their own (fairly strict) [standards](http://www.bbc.co.uk/guidelines/futuremedia/technical/browser_support.shtml).

Specifically the [anim](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/docs/1.7/furtherinfo/anim/) function.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished through the use of jQuery.